# Web Solution and Problem with NameSpace

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I have a Web Project in Visual Studio 2010 I use asp.net 4 c#.

I have a folder structure like this:

```
~Cms/AdminCms/MasterPages/AdminCms.Master
```

and relative namespace:

```
WebProject.Web.Cms.AdminCms.MasterPages
```

I need reference a Master Page in my code: path should be:

```
WebProject.Web.Cms.AdminCms.MasterPages.AdminCms.Master
```

Namespace for my Master Page .cs is:

```
Cms.AdminCms.MasterPages
```

I get an error and I cannot referece the folder MasterPages:

```
The type or namespace name 'MasterPages' does not exist in the namespace 'WebProject.Web.Cms.AdminCms' (are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I can reference any folders in my Web Application but not "MasterPages".

Any idea what is wrong?
Can I force Visual Studio to get this Folder?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GlbboK - did you change the masterpage's namespace in the code-behind but not in the .master or vice-versa?

Comment: Hi in the Master Page CS: namespace Cms.AdminCms.MasterPages and .aspx Inherits="Cms.AdminCms.MasterPages.AdminCms"

Comment: The strange problem is that Folder MasterPages doe not come up event in IntelliSense

Comment: Is this a Web Application Project, or is it a Web Site?

Comment: it is a Web Application Project! So for every folder VS should create a namespace.. not?

Comment: sorry guys was a typo, off course i use 2010 :-)